# Why do my gas optimizations not match this article?

Tags: gas

I tested the following contract in remix, but the gas used appears to be different than the following article, why could this be?

My contract:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.16;

contract Math {
    uint public num;
    // 30494
    function add1() external returns (uint) {
        num++;
    }
    // 30551
    function add2() external returns (uint) {
        ++num;
    }
    // 30650
    function add3() external returns (uint) {
        num += 1;
    }
    // 30661
    function add4() external returns (uint) {
        num = num + 1;
    }
}
```

Theirs: https://dev.to/jamiescript/gas-saving-techniques-in-solidity-324c

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT;

pragma solidity ^0.8.3;

contract One{
   uint256 public number;
  //Gas used : 43800
   function incrementByOne() public returns (uint256){
      number += 1;
      return number;
   }
}

contract Two{
   uint256 public number;
   //Gas used : 43787
   function incrementByOne() public returns (uint256){
     number = number + 1;
     return number;
   }
}

contract Three{
   uint256 public number;
   //Gas used : 43634
   function incrementByOne() public returns (uint256){
       return number++;
   }
}

contract Four{
   uint256 public number;
   //Gas used : 43628
   function incrementByOne() public returns (uint256){
       return ++number;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few reasons for the difference in gas usage between your contract and the one in the article:

- Although all these operations are identical, evm compiler doesn’t treat them the same way
- Your contract uses 'external' while the article's contract uses 'public' for function visibility, which could cause variations in gas usage.
- Unlike the article's contract, you're not returning any value in your functions, which might cause a difference in gas usage.
- The solidity version is different on both contracts, which can also alter the gas usage.
- Function names can also impact gas consumption. For more details, you can check out this article: https://medium.com/joyso/solidity-how-does-function-name-affect-gas-consumption-in-smart-contract-47d270d8ac92

If you're looking to optimize further, you can also use `unchecked {}` for your math operations if you're sure that no overflow/underflow is possible here.

I'll suggest you to read that article if you want to optimize your contract further: https://betterprogramming.pub/the-ultimate-100-point-checklist-before-sending-your-smart-contract-for-audit-af9a5b5d95d0